# Validating rdf:Seq with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, sequence, rdf

[`rdf:Seq`](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_seq) is a sequence of RDF properties `rdf:_1`, `rdf:_2`, `rdf:_3`...

Can it be validated using a SPARQL 1.1 query? For example, if the sequence is valid, an `ASK` query should return `true`, otherwise `false`.

The constraints that I can think of right now:

- must start with `rdf:_1`
- no repeated properties (`rdf:_2`, `rdf:_2`)
- no "holes" in the sequence (`rdf:_2`, `rdf:_4`)

I suspect a completely generic solution can be difficult due to the absence of recursion in SPARQL. But a pragmatic solution that validates a finite number of members (say 30 or 50) would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Does it need to be done purely with SPARQL/SHACL? If not, you can just query the URI for all elements in the sequence and use the features of a programming language to compare the URI values (eg python)

Comment: We have SPARQL-based constraint validation as part of a data-driven architecture, so yes :)

Answer (score 3):

One could just check, if there is some item with another item of the same position or if there is an item without direct predecessor. Unfortunately, this requires some ugly and expensive string operations, so this will probably take longer on large datasets. This query ignores that the duplicate might actually be the same (`owl:sameAs`).

Sample Data:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/>

ex:a a rdf:Seq;
    rdf:_1 ex:a1 ;
    rdf:_2 ex:a2 .
ex:b a rdf:Bag;
    rdf:_1 ex:b1 ;
    rdf:_1 ex:b2 .
ex:c a rdf:Alt;
    rdf:_2 ex:c1 .
ex:d a rdf:Seq;
    rdf:_0 ex:d1 ;
    rdf:_1 ex:d2 .
```

Query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?container ?containerMembershipProperty ?item ?error WHERE {
  {
    ?container a rdf:Seq .
  } UNION {
    ?container a rdf:Bag .
  } UNION {
    ?container a rdf:Alt .
  }
  {
    BIND("Duplicated Index" AS ?error)
    ?container ?containerMembershipProperty ?item .
    FILTER strstarts(str(?containerMembershipProperty),"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_")
    FILTER EXISTS {
      ?container ?containerMembershipProperty ?item2 .
      FILTER (?item!=?item2)
    }
  } UNION {
    BIND("Missing Predecessor" AS ?error)
    ?container ?containerMembershipProperty ?item .
    BIND(xsd:integer(STRAFTER(STR(?containerMembershipProperty),"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_")) - 1 AS ?index)
    BIND(IRI(CONCAT("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_", STR(?index))) AS ?previousContainerMembershipProperty)
    FILTER (?index >= 1)
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?container ?previousContainerMembershipProperty ?item3
    }
  } UNION {
    BIND("Illegal Index" AS ?error)
    ?container ?containerMembershipProperty ?item .
    BIND(xsd:integer(STRAFTER(STR(?containerMembershipProperty),"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_")) AS ?index)
    FILTER (?index < 1)
  }
}
ORDER BY ?container ?containerMembershipProperty ?item
```

Result:

| container | containerMembershipProperty | item | error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http://example.org/b | rdf:_1 | http://example.org/b1 | "Duplicated Index" |
| http://example.org/b | rdf:_1 | http://example.org/b2 | "Duplicated Index" |
| http://example.org/c | rdf:_2 | http://example.org/c1 | "Missing Predecessor" |
| http://example.org/d | rdf:_0 | http://example.org/d1 | "Illegal Index" |